# ¿Cómo almacenos los datos que se le pide al usuario?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, array

**1 Solicite al usuario el ingreso por teclado de 3 notas
2 Saque la media de las notas
3 Muestre por pantalla
si la nota es menor que 5 ('suspenso');
si la nota es mayor o igual 5 y menor que 7('aprobado');
si es mayor o igual que 7 y menor o igual que 10 ('sobresaliente');**

[image: Esto es lo que llevo, apenas estoy comenzando con js]

Comment: Código como texto, así como explicar que si hace y que no hace aún ese script, aquí puedes leer [ask]

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- puedes convertir las candenas en numero y asi poder calcular la media.
- luego que calculas la media puede hecer un if anidado para comprobar que la condicion se cumpla y mostrar el texto para cada condición validada.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. No pongas imágenes donde debería ir código, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.